# Evince is displaying correctly but is printing incorrectly

Tags: pdf, evince, postscript

I was given a structural engineering PDF document with some yellow highlighted text which displays correctly in Evince like this:

[image]

But when I try to print that same page it shows the yellow, but not the hi-lighted black text, so it ends up printing like this:

[image]

Thus missing the text "SEISMIC DESIGN CATEGORY...".

The same problem occurs if I try and preview the text before printing, where the preview is surprisingly wrong, or if I print to a PDF file and then try to open that file with Evince to view or print it.

---

**With a little hacking I did find two workarounds** 1) print that page to a postscript file (*.ps) and then open that postscript file with Evince and then printing works correctly for this document.  2) Use Okular which seems to print this just fine.  (I'm now guessing this is an Evince bug.)

So it seems like the Evince pdf to postscript conversion when printing is a bit off, but ok when you print pdf to ps.

Is there is a better solution where printing from Evince doesn't stumble, so I don't have to worry that what's printed is different from what's on the screen?

---

*I'm running Debian 10, my Evince version is 3.30.2, and I'm printing to an hp4020 printer with CUPS, which is all I've got to test it with at the moment.*

Comment: Since it works OK in Okular, report it as a bug in Evince.   And maybe try `qpdfview` too.

Comment: @cas - Tried qpdfview and it prints properly.  So reported it as a bug.  Thanks

Comment: Evince replied:  "

Andre Klapper commented:

    evince is version 3.30.2 (from Debian 10 repository).

Unfortunately that version is ancient and not supported anymore by GNOME developers. There will not be any bug fixes or feature additions by GNOME developers for the version that you use.

Please feel free to reopen this issue if this situation still happens with a more recent version (currently: Evince 40.x). Feel also free to report this in the issue tracking system of your Linux distribution if your Linux distribution still supports that version,"

Comment: But the good news is that qpdfview works great!